# How to get current Year from timestamp (solidity)

Tags: solidity, remix, datetime

I want to keep track of each nft count per year. so I need to get the year part of current timestamp.

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) public mintCountPerYear;
```

this dictionary will hold the nft-id and in the value there will be year and count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be

```
Uint currentYear = (block.timestamp / 31557600) + 1970;
```

Assuming that a year is 365,25 days (to account for leap years) and a day is 86400 seconds (which isnt always the case).
Im pretty sure thats the best you can get though.